# Relation between central and derived series in Lie algebras and Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I wonder if there exists a one-to-one correspondence between the terms of the derived series of a Lie algebra and a Lie group. In that case, I suppose that the Lie algebra associated to one term in the derived series of a Lie group is the corresponding term of that series in the Lie algebra associated to the group.

I assume that the same happens for central series.

Comment: No. As you can check with easy examples, the number of terms after which each of these series stabilizes is not even always the same.

Comment: Actually it's unclear if you're asking about a relation between central and derived series (which I assumed in my previous comment), or between, for each of these, between that in the Lie algebra and that in the Lie group. In the latter case, there's a correspondence. 1-to-1 correspondence (i.e. bijection), it should be clarified between what and what.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have edited my question. Would you have a reference of that fact?

Comment: I guess it can be found in most textbooks on Lie groups. Having in mind that the corresponding "analytic subgroups" need not be closed. Also it assumes the Lie group to be connected otherwise it's not true.